# Duplicate enum member names in Cython - redeclaration error?

Tags: python, enums, cython, cythonize

Cython doesn't seem to allow me to reuse enum member names.

I have the following enums that I'm trying to cythonize:

```
from enum import Enum

class Fruit(Enum):

    UNKNOWN = 0
    APPLE = 1
    ORANGE = 2

class Animal(Enum):

    UNKNOWN = 0
    DOG = 1
    CAT = 2
```

But the following results in a `'UNKNOWN' redeclared` compilation error:

```
cpdef enum Fruit:

    UNKNOWN = 0
    APPLE = 1
    ORANGE = 2    

cpdef enum Animal:

    UNKNOWN = 0
    DOG = 1
    CAT =
```

How should I fix the above?

Also, I'd ideally like to use `NULL` as the enum member names instead of `UNKNOWN`. But it seems that `NULL` is a privileged keyword for Cython though it's not for CPython. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

In C, the following code [would not compile](https://www.godbolt.org/z/INJeDK):

```c
enum Foo{
    A
};

enum Bar{
    A
};
```

because in C, enums don’t introduce a new namescope and thus a name clash happens if you use the same identifier `A` for both types `Foo` and `Bar`.

Cython would translate (if it would just apply its usual scheme and not stop with a compiler-error):

```
#foo.pyx
cpdef enum Fruit:
    UNKNOWN = 0   

cpdef enum Animal:
    UNKNOWN = 0
```

to something like

```c
enum __pyx_t_3foo_Fruit {
  __pyx_e_3foo_UNKNOWN = 0
};

enum __pyx_t_3foo_Animal {
  __pyx_e_3foo_UNKNOWN = 0
};
```

and as we have seen, this is not valid C, so Cython's choice is to generate an error. A "problem" is that Cython doesn't include the type name (`Fruit`, `Animal`) into the generated enum-value-name, so while in Cython you would be able to differentiate between them as `Fruit.UNKNOWN` and `Animal.UNKNOWN`, they would map to the same C-identifier.

There are at least two options:

**A:** The usual strategy in C is to use a prefix to differentiate between the enums, e.g.:

```
cpdef enum Fruit:
       FRUIT_UNKNOWN = 0

cpdef enum Animal:
      ANIMAL_UNKNOWN = 1
```

**or B:** you can let Cython to do this work by putting them in different pxd-files, which are imported in the resulting pyx-file:

```
# Fruit.pxd
cpdef enum Fruit:
    UNKNOWN = 0

#Animal.pxd
cpdef enum Animal:
    UNKNOWN = 0

# foo.pyx:
cimport Fruit
cimport Animal

# use Fruit.UNKNOWN and Animal.UNKNOWN
```

in the resulting code, the enum-names will have the module names (i.e. `Fruit` and `Animal`) and thus are not the same from C-compiler's point of view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd imagine there's some hacky way to replicate the Python version if it works fine on CPython? I'll accept your answer in 2 weeks if there's no better approach.